# Face landmarks detection with dlib

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision, dlib, facial-landmark-alignment

I have the following code:

```
image_1 = cv2.imread('headshot13-14-2.jpg')
image_1_rgb = cv2.cvtColor(image_1, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
image_1_gray = cv2.cvtColor(image_1_rgb, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
p = "shape_predictor_68_face_landmarks.dat"
detector = dlib.get_frontal_face_detector()
predictor = dlib.shape_predictor(p)

face = detector(image_1_gray)
face_landmarks = predictor(image_1_gray, face)
```

And I get the following error for the line `face = predictor(image_1_gray, face)`:

```
TypeError: __call__(): incompatible function arguments. The following argument types are supported:
    1. (self: dlib.shape_predictor, image: array, box: dlib.rectangle) -> dlib.full_object_detection
```

However, I checked the type of face (it's dlib.rectangles) and the image_1_gray is a numpy ndarray.
Does anyone have any idea why this error still show up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`face` variable may contain multiple values, therefore you need to use `predictor` for each value.

For instance:

```py
for (i, rect) in enumerate(face):
    face_landmarks = predictor(image_1_gray, rect)
```

To display the detected values on the face:

```py
shp = face_utils.shape_to_np(face_landmarks)
```

To use `face_utils`, you need to install `imutils`.

Most probably your `shp` variable size is `(68, 2)`. Where `68` is detected points in the face and the `2` is the `(x, y)` coordinate tuples.

Now, to draw the detected face on the image:

- First, get the coordinates

  - ```py
    x = rect.left()
    y = rect.top()
    w = rect.right() - x
    h = rect.bottom() - y
    ```
- Draw the coordinates:

  - ```py
    cv2.rectangle(image_1, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (0, 255, 0), 2)
    ```
- There may be multiple face in the image, so you may want to label them

  - ```py
    cv2.putText(image_1, "Face #{}".format(i + 1), (x - 10, y - 10),
                cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.5, (0, 255, 0), 2)
    ```
- Now draw the 68 points on the face:

  - ```py
    for (x, y) in shp:
        cv2.circle(image_1, (x, y), 1, (0, 0, 255), -1)
    ```

Result:

[image]

Code:

---

```py
for (i, rect) in enumerate(face):
    face_landmarks = predictor(image_1_gray, rect)
    shp = face_utils.shape_to_np(face_landmarks)
    x = rect.left()
    y = rect.top()
    w = rect.right() - x
    h = rect.bottom() - y
    cv2.rectangle(image_1, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (0, 255, 0), 2)
    cv2.putText(image_1, "Face #{}".format(i + 1), (x - 10, y - 10),
                cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.5, (0, 255, 0), 2)
    for (x, y) in shp:
        cv2.circle(image_1, (x, y), 1, (0, 0, 255), -1)

cv2.imshow("face", image_1)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

You can also look at the [tutorial](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2017/04/03/facial-landmarks-dlib-opencv-python/)